# Spotipy: Searching a track with a non-English name

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am currently tracking to look up a track's ID based on the song and artist name. I am using the api and spotify library (which can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/spotify/).

Here is an example:

- I want to search for this song. The name of this song is called Gee and is sung by 소녀시대. Notice the artist name is in Korean, but in English they are known as Girl's Generation.

When I search for this on spotify using the term "Gee 소녀시대", the following results pop up as expected.

[image]

However, If i were to use the following code to search for this on python, the following error pops up.

```
sp.search(q='artist:' + '소녀시대' + ' track:' + 'Gee', type='track')
```

[image]

Is there anyway for me to search such that the result shows up as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Played around with the code and it actually just requires a very simple solution

```
sp.search(q='Gee 소녀시대', type='track')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).